# What to do if system administrator does not support system image?

Tags: windows-7, disk-image

In case of a system failure, I wanted to create a system image. However, it requires administrative password. System admin asked me why you want to create a system image; because we don't support it already.

What to do if the system image is not supported by the admin? Does it make sense to insist on creating an image or asking something else such as "back-up the system"?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Sometimes I am not direct to explain my problem, but it sounds @MikeC got my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern system builds are typically deployed dynamically, so one build can accommodate multiple hardware platforms using scripts to determine what action to run depending on the platform, MDT and SCCM and two Microsoft solutions that allow this. The required software/applications can also dynamically deployed in a similar fashion. So a system can be rebuilt quickly and effectively without dozens of disk images.

You system image would take up a lot of space and only be of any use to you and that device.

Again, typically all your userdata would be stored on network storage (SAN or NAS) so this would not be captured by a system image.

These may be reasons that a system image is valueless in your instance.

What exactly is the critical data you want to be backed up?

Ensuring that data is backed up may be all that is required and should your device need to be rebuilt that can be accommodated without a system image.

Comment: The data is already backed up. So I don't worry to lose it. However, if the system fails, I thought keeping an image is advantageous than installing several software. Now, it sounds like the system image will not work anyway!

Comment: How many applications do you have installed and how time consuming is it to install them? I gather that if you do not have admin rights, this is not even your job to do that?

Comment: I use some custom applications (simulators) that requires my special attention to setup. I remember that system admins gave me the right to arrange the configurations with the temporary rights. That was my concern!

Comment: sounds like you need to have a meeting instead of posing questions on SF